# unable to modify Base application theme

Tags: android, android-manifest

Without editing Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and values\styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I get mistake like this

> 02-09 20:42:47.567 24389-24389/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      Process: com.example.golendukhin.settingsSwitcher, PID: 24389
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.golendukhin.settingsSwitcher/com.example.golendukhin.settingsSwitcher.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                          at com.example.golendukhin.settingsSwitcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749) 
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                          at com.example.golendukhin.settingsSwitcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749) 
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                          at com.example.golendukhin.settingsSwitcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749) 
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with the design library.
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:192)
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:186)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                          at com.example.golendukhin.settingsSwitcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)

The question is - what kind of mistake I made.
Creating new "Hello World!" project with same manifest and style files works fine. In both projects Main Activity extends AppCompatActivity.
Totally stuck trying to realize what happend with project.

Googling provided me with idea to change Theme in manifest.
I did so and replaced

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

with

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Theme became dark and styling it in "Style" had no effect.
I even removed base applicaion theme - no effect. So, this is not a proper way.
Need any help, I don't even know what to do next.

Comment: the logs shows that you have some problem with layout xml file and not with themes

Comment: This [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_styles_and_themes.htm) will help you

Comment: lalit jadhav really helped. Thanks, man. I wish I could read this tutorial before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is preaty unobvious.
I have removed `<!--android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">-->` from "activity" node in Manifest, renamed `<style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to  `<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` and applyed my renamed MainTheme to all application in "application" node in Manifest `android:theme="@style/MainTheme">`
App now works. Probably "AppTheme" is predefined somehow in android.
Thanks to  lalit jadhav for an advised tutotial. He really helped.

Manifest
...

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <!--android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

...

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```